Streaming yaml parsing, but Decode twice
I use that to parse yaml with several docs in one file:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

type Spec struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

func main() {
    f := io.Reader(os.Stdin)
    d := yaml.NewDecoder(f)
    for {
        var spec Spec
        err := d.Decode(&spec)
        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("name is '%s'\n", spec.Name)
    }
}

Now I want to decode the current object twice.
Depending on the name in the current doc has, I want to parse that:
type Special struct {
    Integer     string    `yaml:"integer"`
}

but if I use d.Decode() I would parse the next doc ...
How to solve that?

a side note: spec is never nil in your code, you can remove the if spec == nil { check.

BTW LeGEC is correct: you appear to not have fully grasped the concept of pointers: you do not need to call new(Spec) (which allocates an anonymous variable of type Spec and returns a pointers to) and then take an addres of that pointer to pass to Decode: it would suffice to just declare a variable of type Spec "the normal way" (see var si Special in the code example in my answer).

@kostix yes, you are right. I updated the question. Thank you

Unmarshal the doc to a Node first, and then decode the resulting node as much times as you want using the Node's Decode method (see the docs).
A modified example would look like this:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
)

const data = `
---
name: "foo"
integer: 42
---
name: "bar"
integer: 12
`

type Spec struct {
    Name string `yaml:"name"`
}

type Special struct {
    Integer string `yaml:"integer"`
}

func main() {
    dec := yaml.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data))

    for {
        var node yaml.Node

        err := dec.Decode(&node)
        if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        spec := new(Spec)

        err = node.Decode(&spec)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        // check it was parsed
        if spec == nil {
            fmt.Println("# spec is nil")
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("name is '%s'\n", spec.Name)

        var si Special
        err = node.Decode(&si)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("integer is: ", si.Integer)
    }
}

Playground.
